# Blurred Background Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My Logo on header is disappearing whenever I open the modal, I know that the cause of the problem is my code for making the background blurred when the modal is opened.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
        <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);border: none">
                <div class="modal-body p-0">
                    <img data-dismiss="modal" src="#" class="img-fluid img-responsive portfolioimg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body.modal-open >:not(.modal) {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(90%);
    filter: blur(5px) grayscale(90%);
}
```

Comment: you want the background blur except logo?

Comment: Whether it will work this way at all, first of all depends on where your logo is located in the DOM tree, in relation to what you have shown above. You are applying the filter to every child of body that is not the modal itself - so for you to be able to not apply this filter on your logo, it would need to be on the same level, resp. nested into a child of body that you can remove the filter from completely.

Comment: No, I want everything on the background of modal blurred including the logo, but what's happening on the logo is its literally disappearing not just getting blurred.

Comment: This is how menu normally looks like:
https://imgur.com/a/6EbcqGG

And this is how it looks like when the loginmodal is open:
https://imgur.com/a/IcSxpAo